# Индексируются ли атрибуты тегов?

Tags: seo

Возник вопрос по оформлению страницы на которой используется массив ссылок с их описанием: как лучше их представить? Вроде бы удобно представить каждую ссылку с использованием атрибута title, который позволяет выводить всплывающий текст с описанием данной ссылки (а именно сайта, на который она ведет) при наведении на него указателя мыши. С другой стороны, можно создать таблицу, в первой колонке которой будет ссылка, а во второй описание. Во втором случае текста на странице будет гораздо больше и он будет проиндексирован поисковыми ботами. А будет ли проиндексирован текст в первом случае, т.е. при использовании атрибута title тега ? Что предпочесть с точки зрения SEO?

Answer (score 0):

> А будет ли проиндексирован текст в первом случае, т.е. при использовании атрибута title тега ?

Да

> Что предпочесть с точки зрения SEO?

Оба варианта